# How can I make a festival image post app in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am developing a festival image post app in react-native.

I have a question regarding the possibility to uses react-native
library for developing the app (ios/android) which will able to make festival image post app fantastic performance and UI.

so how can I make a Festival Image Post app in react native?
like brandsport app:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for react native UI library try this one https://galio.io/
it would help with the developer experience for creating custom UI.. but this one is opinionated, can try it first !

for creating forms, can use react-hook-forms to help with easier validation https://react-hook-form.com/

for api calls can use Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/) or Supabase (https://supabase.io/) to create easy backend service without code.

These are simple tools that I suggest to check to create a simple react native app.. there are still many more to check and search for. It is a journey to create an app :D. Cheers !